# Text box while inserting a new row into the table

Tags: html, html-table, rows

I am to enter a new row into the table, the issue I am having is that I want the new row to be like the first row, where it is textboxes not just words..

```
function displayResult() {
  var table=document.getElementById("customers");
  var row=table.insertRow(0);
  var item=row.insertCell(0);
  var link=row.insertCell(1);
  var price=row.insertCell(2);
  var comment=row.insertCell(3);
  item.innerHTML="words";
  link.innerHTML="words";
  price.innerHTML="words";
  comment.innerHTML="words";
}
```

Original line in which I want the new rows to mimic.

```
</tr>
<td>
  <input type ="text" name= "item" placeholder= "Item Description" />
</td>
```

Here is the button code that calls the function

```
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert New Item</button>
```

Comment: Could you update your post to include the exact markup you're starting with AND the exact markup you want to create? Also, don't ever use inline js (like onclick in your html).

Comment: I am using HTML with PHP

Comment: Also have CSS as well for the table design

Comment: Markup means html. I'm asking you to show me what the markup should look like after you run your function. Your description is unclear.

Comment: What I would like is when a user hits the button Insert New Item, that a new row would appear exactly like </tr>
<td>
  <input type ="text" name= "item" placeholder= "Item Description" />
</td>  Where it would add a new row in a format that the user could enter in information.

Comment: Sorry if that is still unclear..  Pretty much what I want the function to do is somehow copy the </tr>
<td>
  <input type ="text" name= "item" placeholder= "Item Description" />
</td>  Everytime the user has to enter an item.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. This will also award you some reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/obekorE/1/edit)

All you're looking for is `cloneNode()`, or you can just create each element again, append them and insert the row, but that isn't as clean. Some issues with your code: Don't use `<br>`. That's long deprecated. You should be using css margin/padding/position for that purpose. Don't use `onclick` or any inline js in your html. That has never been a good practice. Instead, get a reference to the element and add the event listener with javascript. Also, your row/cell html is invalid. You have your row closed before the cell...

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="myRow"> <!-- you can use this id to find the row with javascript -->
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item Description">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="myButton" type="button">Insert New Item</button> <!-- you can use this id to find the button with javascript -->
```

js:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton'); //get button with id "myButton"
var myRow = document.getElementById('myRow'); //get row with id "myRow"

myButton.addEventListener('click', function() { //add click function to "myButton"
  var newRow = myRow.cloneNode(); //clone the row
  myRow.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, myRow.nextSibling); //add newRow after "myRow"
});
```

Comment: Looks like I do not have the java file that calls addEventListener.. I am receiving an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of Null

Comment: Not only am I new at Stack I am also new at coding in general..  In the formatt of my question how would I implement your answer?  Would it be something like this

Comment: @user3038531 did you not look at my live demo link? I am showing the code working!! It IS implemented.

Comment: function displayResult()
{
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
var myRow = document.getElementById('myRow');

};

</script>
<script>
myButton.addEventListener('click', displayResult() 
  var newRow = myRow.cloneNode();
  myRow.parentNode.insertBefore(newRow, myRow.nextSibling);
</script>

Comment: @user3038531 there's no need for all of that code in these comments. My answer is complete and working with everything that you need. I added comments on everything. Now it's your job to read my answer and study html and javascript.